# Number Format Exception in service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, numbers

Code

```
    final EditText wid = (EditText) myview.findViewById(R.id.width);
    final EditText hie = (EditText) myview.findViewById(R.id.height);
    Button mSave = (Button) myview.findViewById(R.id.save);
    Button mCancel = (Button) myview.findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    final String mWidth = wid.getText().toString();
    final String mHeight = hie.getText().toString();

    mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(mWidth)>= 500 && Integer.parseInt(mWidth) <= 1000 &&
                    Integer.parseInt(mHeight) >= 500 && Integer.parseInt(mHeight) <= 1500) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ResizeService.this, UsersService.class);
                intent.putExtra("Width", mWidth);
                intent.putExtra("Height", mHeight);
                startService(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check whether the data you entered matches the requirements", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The entered numbers are integers without a decimal. But still getting error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
>                                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Services.ResizeService$1.onClick(ResizeService.java:57)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21193)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)

The editTexts aren't empty either... im typing numbers but still getting error

Also this is in a service by the way...
The error is on the line of the if statement

Comment: check if **mWidth** and **mHeight** are not empty !!

Comment: clearly Integer.parseInt() giving you this exception. make sure you put input  type number and check for empty string on your edittext to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to move

```
final String mWidth = wid.getText().toString();
final String mHeight = hie.getText().toString();
```

inside the onclick.  that way you get the values when you click instead of when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
    final String mWidth = wid.getText().toString();
    final String mHeight = hie.getText().toString();
```

I would do

```
    final int mWidth = wid.getText();
    final int mHeight = hie.getText();
```

And in the xml I would set the inputType of the `EditText` to just numbers.

And then remove the `Integer.parseInt` and you just place it inside your onClick since you are pressing a button to get the values inside an `EditText`, if you try to get the values before, your variables `mWidth` and `mHeight` will return null since there is nothing inside them before you click your button.